# Replacing dimmer light switch...new switch doesn't seem to have enough wires

Tags: dimmer-switch

2002 light switch with dimmer next to fan switch (separate). Bought new lutron switch and looking at directions for single pole/3 doesn't make sense. Have pics of existing dimmer switch. 2 black wires and bare wire going FROM house to switch. Also has a red wire and a black wire coming FROM switch to house. Only 2 screws on box are used, one for bare and one for the 2 black wires together coming FROM house to switch. My new Lutron switch is notike this at all. Any help? Different switch option? How to re-wire

Comment: Pictures will help.  The bare wire is on a green screw?  Any other screw is bad, very bad.

Comment: where are you located?